# Please help me with file upload with text fields in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

Please help me with file upload with text fields details going to database in codeigniter. ( for example i want image name and some another form field going to database and file uploads to server)

Also how do i stop the form submission in database upon page resfresh ?

Comment: We need to see some code because we don't know how your site or database works.

Answer (score 1):

The best I can do is link you to the relevant pages so that you can learn more. If you provide more information I might be able to help you more:

File upload:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Database:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/index.html

I recommend using the Active Record part of the database library:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html

As for how to stop form submission on page refresh, simply use redirect('controller/method'); after you have handled the form data. For example:

```
if(!is_bool($this->input->post('fieldvalue'))
{
$this->model->writeToDB($_POST);
redirect('controller/method');
}
```

so that every time data is submitted, it is added to the db and then the redirect will revisit the page, thus the browser won't remember what was in the post array and that will solve the problem.

Comment: yup, upload then redirect. That way, your refresh will not initiate another upload.

Answer (score 0):

view:

```
<form method="post" action="#">
  <input type="text" name="foo"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

controller:

```
 $this->load->model('yourmodel','model',true);
 if(isset($_POST['text']))
    $result = $this->model->doQuery($_POST['text']);
```

model:

```
  function doQuery($text){
      $result = $this->db->query("insert into table $text");
      return $result;
  }
```

(edit) upload:

```
use $_FILES and move_uploaded file
```